# Hiding a separate DIV from a dropdown menu list item

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jquery to hide a div in a query when the selector element is clicked on:

```
$(function() { // Shorthand for $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.decline').click(function() {
            $(this).closest('div').animate({backgroundColor: '#003'}, 'slow').
                  animate({opacity: 'hide'}, 'slow');
      });
});
```

Here is the row and button that it currently works on; a user clicks on the button and the div fades away.:

```
<div class="<?php echo ($accept == '1')?'showop':'show';?>">
<span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $record;  ?></span>
<span><a href="#" **class="decline"** **data-dropdown="#dropdown-1**"  id1="<?php echo $id1; ?>" data-order1="<?php echo $name; ?>"><input type="button" title="declined" value="Decline" /></a></span>
</div>
```

I have now added a drop down to the button; it is added to the button by the id #dropdown-1 and the drop down is as follows:

```
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#1" class="decline"><span>Option One</span></a></li> 
        <li><a href="#2">Option Two
</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to change the functionality of the animation and execute it when a user clicks on on of the drop down items. The div IDs and classes are part of the query and cannot be used as selectors (there are many of the same on the same page).

Upon the suggestion of another user I tried the parent selector as follows:

```
jQuery('.decline').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).parent('div').animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
});
```

But that hasn't worked either.

If anyone has any ideas on what I might be doing wrong I would appreciate he help!

EDIT FOR ADDED JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/2hvzM/1/

**REMEMBER: The div IDs are being generated by the queried rowid so I MUST use parent/child/closest for my selector...just not sure which one.**

EDIT with scrowler's solution and my additions:

```
$('.dropdown ul li').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dropdownID = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    // find the .show div by this ID and apply effects
    var showDiv = $('a[data-dropdown="#' + dropdown-1 + '"]').closest('div.show');
    showDiv.animate({backgroundColor: '#003'}, 'slow').animate({opacity: 'hide'}, 'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$('.dropdown ul li').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this prevents your anchor doing its default behaviour (redirect)
    $(this).closest('div').animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
});
```

This targets the `.dropdown` div(s) as the target, applying a click handler to children anchor elements using the [delegated-events approach](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). You then use `closest('div')` to select the container and apply your effects to it.

## Update:

Having seen [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hvzM/1/), here's an updated answer that will hide the div which isn't a parent or child of the element you're actually clicking.

I've used the `id` attribute of the dropdown's div container as a common link between the two. So get that `id`, use it to find the original button that you clicked to trigger the dropdown, find the parent `div.show` of that, and apply effects to that.

```
$('.dropdown ul li').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dropdownID = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    // find the .show div by this ID and apply effects
    var showDiv = $('a[data-dropdown="#' + dropdownID + '"]').closest('div.show');
    showDiv.animate({backgroundColor: '#003'}, 'slow').animate({opacity: 'hide'}, 'slow');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2hvzM/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, the div still doesn't hide. I know it has to be the selector, but I cannot figure out which to use.

Comment: I would but its using this plugin for the dropdown: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/

Comment: You can link to external resources in JSFiddle, should only take you a couple of minutes to set up but it will save you a lot of time with people trying to help you solve your problem.

Comment: scrowler - The parent id of the button is the parent id of the dropdown: I added my edit above based on your recc. - Still no go!

Comment: I must be misunderstanding your problem - can you have a look at my fiddle and tell me what it is doing wrong?

Comment: your FIDDLE works as needed; I just cannot replicate it in my code. It should work just as yours did. The dropdown is located at the bottom of the html file (per the plugin directions)..would that have an effect?

Answer (score 0):

Your first try was ALMOST ok

Instead of parent('div') use parents('div'), like this:

```
jQuery('.decline').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).parents('div').animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input; it didnt solve the issue, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: Your answer will apply effects to every parent div element that a `.decline` element has, right up to the top of the DOM. `parent()` stops with the first it finds.

Comment: that's what parents do, but not what parent do. Parent will stop in the first level, not the first "selector" you pass

Comment: ..and there is the issue. The parent div of the .decline element IS NOT what needs hiding. The parent div of the button .decline is the drop down wrapper; the div that needs hiding is the div #show that is in the query. The two are completely separate from each other. The HTML is my FIDDLE is the output if the query.

Comment: I see that @scrowler is helping you, already, and it seems to be pretty close to what you need, so I'll get some sleep. Anyway, at the time of my answer, the question wasn't completely clear, so I don't see the reason for the downvote
Anyways, good luck